# Invalid property value

Tags: css, background

I tried to set the element's CSS to this: `url('example.png') center center 100% 100% no-repeat`

But I've got an error: Invalid property value

The definition should be allright, because the background property value should look like this: `background: color position size repeat`

I have no idea, what do I wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
background: url('example.png') center center / 100% 100% no-repeat;
```

Note the slash

Comment: "See background-size. This property must be specified after background-position, separated with the '/' character.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Thr position is already defined using center center. Using 100% 100% is like again defining a position. try to remove 100% 100% and check.
Syntax is: url repeat/no-repeat scroll/no-scroll rightposition topposition color